# Enable VLC Player to automatically reconnect to a stream

Tags: cmd, ip, vlc, ip-camera

We have two screens in our factory that connect to IP cameras using VLC. Due to network hiccups, VLC loses sometimes the connection with those cameras. What I am looking for is that VLC will automatically try to reconnect with the cameras after a loss of stream input. Any suggestion on how this could be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50776951/troubleshoot-failed-auto-reconnect-in-vlc-network-stream-via-settings-or-python?rq=1

Comment: It's failing to reconnect. For me it fails even if I connect on VPN, radio stream stops. Then I have to click stop and play again!