# Troubleshoot failed auto-reconnect in VLC network stream via settings or Python LibVLC API

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

I'm using VLC to stream a wireless IP camera to a wall-mounted monitor that's connected to a tiny Debian computer.

Please note that *Auto-reconnect* from `Tools > Preferences > All > Input / Codecs > Access Modules > HTTP(S)` is **enabled** already.

**Problem:** after 30 min - 1 hour the stream disconnects. Only the orange VLC cone displays.

**Symptoms:** I can easily reload it manually. The *Auto-reconnect* radio box had no effect.

**Question:** Is there a configuration, script-based, or other approach that I can leverage to automatically re-connect?

I am studying the [CLI documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/) and the Python bindings for LibVLC. I actually don't see anything useful in the documentation.

[LibVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC) and its [Python bindings](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=generated/3.0/vlc.py;h=025331241e25bd6b39a6ede8a7a6b022d390ed6f;hb=HEAD) seem to provide a complete reproduction of VLC from the ground up, such as what you'd use to fork or embed the application. I'm sure there must be a way to use that somehow, but it's not apparent to me yet and this seems like an incredibly heavy-lifting approach to solving this bug.

Comment: Try digging in the `vlcrc` file (on Linux - $HOME/.config/vlc/vlcrc). It has a host of `timeout` settings and #http-reconnect=0 plus #http-continuous=0

Comment: @RolfofSaxony OK thanks, I will try that in a few hours. If it works I will let you know and I hope you will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-reconnect in VLC did not work for me at all and I think this is still an [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/790216). Therefore, I switched to [Streamlink](https://streamlink.github.io), which uses VLC. Here the process stops, if the stream disconnects. With a infinity loop you can let it automatically try to reconnect forever:

```sh
while :; do streamlink <link-of-stream> best -p vlc --retry-streams <seconds-until-retry>; sleep <seconds-until-retry>; done
```

[I use it](https://gist.github.com/christianll9/ef348a4fe181026288f6c7bcc9f0e98c) for YouTube streams. I am not sure, whether it also works for network streams.